# Regex: End match at a special character or end of string

Tags: regex

I want to get the handle out of a YouTube channel url.

The url usually like this:
`https://www.youtube.com/@ChannelHandle`

I want to get only the handle, so I come up with this regex : `/(?<=\/@).*.(?=\/|$|)/`

My problem is that it stops at the end of the url, but it doesn't stop at `/`

How to stop either at `/` or string end?

Comment: `(/|$)`would be `/` or end of string. Where is regex being used? Maybe https://regex101.com/r/N7LgUF/1 or https://regex101.com/r/C7P59t/1 (if JS)

Comment: FYI: `.*.` can be simplified to `.+`

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra `|` in your alternatives at the end, so the lookahead matches an empty string anywhere.

You should also use a non-greedy quantifier so it stops at either `/` or the end of the string, whichever comes first. A greedy quantifier will keep going until the last match of the lookahead.

```
/(?<=\/@).+?(?=\/|$)/
```

But a simpler way is just to match a sequence of characters not including `/`:

```
/(?<=\/@)[^/]+/
```